# How to Disable Save As Excel 97-2003 using VBA to prevent bypassing salt?

Tags: vba, password-protection, salt

I would like to disable the possibility to save a workbook (specifically) to an Excel 97-2003 workbook. So users cant disable the stronger protection salt, which is introduced in office 2013, and break the password easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible if they can create their own file (they can copy the data out anyway).

But if you're going to provide them a file, you can give it to them as xlsm and block them from doing SaveAs. Put this in `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If SaveAsUI Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```